# Someone tries to hack my Rails app in Ec2. How can I prevent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2

I went to my `access.log` file in my EC2 and I see these:

```
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:04 -0300] "HEAD /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:06 -0300] "HEAD /myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:06 -0300] "HEAD /shopdb/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:06 -0300] "HEAD /program/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:06 -0300] "HEAD /PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:07 -0300] "HEAD /dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:07 -0300] "HEAD /pma/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:07 -0300] "HEAD /db/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:07 -0300] "HEAD /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:07 -0300] "HEAD /database/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:08 -0300] "HEAD /db/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:08 -0300] "HEAD /db/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:08 -0300] "HEAD /sqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:09 -0300] "HEAD /admin/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:09 -0300] "HEAD /admin/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:10 -0300] "HEAD /admin/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:10 -0300] "HEAD /admin/db/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:10 -0300] "HEAD /admin/web/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:17 -0300] "HEAD /php-my-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:17 -0300] "HEAD /PMA2011/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:17 -0300] "HEAD /PMA2012/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:20 -0300] "HEAD /pma2018/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:20 -0300] "HEAD /phpmyadmin2011/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
XYZ.00.11.222 - - [16/Sep/2017:12:30:21 -0300] "HEAD /phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
```

And more and more...

Is there a way to prevent this kind of attack?
I have a Rails App and I can redirect some requests via `routes.rb`, but I don't know how to do this.

If it happened to you, what would you do?
Because I don't know...

My environment info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: 4.2.3
nginx: nginx/1.8.0
passenger -v: 5.0.10
```

I'm using Load Balancer.

Comment: The reality is that any publicly available site is going to be targeted by these types of probes.  You should be aware of these but I wouldn't spend time trying to block it - you'll just be playing [whac-a-mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole) with people trying to break in - as soon as you block one another one will pop up.  Instead, use good security practices in your own code and pay attention to logs from your application.  These random probes will not hurt anything but are annoying.

Comment: @stdunbar you are right. Thanks the advice!

Answer (score 3):

These types are requests are quite common and you can't prevent them if your website is hosted publicly. However there are measures which you can take to throttle the requests coming from an IP or ban the IP totally. There is a gem called [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) which comes quite handy in dealing with these scenarios. Give it a spin and see how it works out for you.

Comment: This gem is really very interesting! I'll test ASAP. Thanks your answer.